# Oracle query- Year to year population trend by city

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this results from an sql query. The table is named 'population' with the columns: region, country, city, year_v and pouplation:

```
REGION  COUNTRY CITY    YEAR_V  POPULATION
europe  france  paris   2015    2.1
europe  france  paris   2017    2.2
europe  france  lyon    2016    .4
europe  spain   madrid  2012    2.9
europe  spain   madrid  2013    3
europe  spain   madrid  2014    3.1
europe  spain   madrid  2016    .8
```

what I need to get from here is the year to year population trend by city, which should look something like this:

```
city    growth   year_diff
Madrid   0.10    2012-2013
Madrid   0.10    2013-2014
Paris    0.10    2015-2017
```

I would appreciate a hint on how i could write a query that returns me this kind of result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `lag()`:

```
select region, country, city,
       year_v, population,
       prev_year_v, prev_population,
       (population - prev_population) as diff
from (select t.*,
             lag(population) over (partition by region, country, city order by year_v) as prev_population,
             lag(year_v) over (partition by region, country, city order by year_v) as prev_year_v,
      from t
     ) t
where prev_year_v is not null;
```

Comment: As usual, I am always `LAG`ging behind you `\:~(` ... +1